# SQLite unable to update data from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I am a rookie in SQLite and I am trying to improve some old databases. The objective is to update the Table Ships with info already in Table Companies.
I have been trying different approaches for some time without success.
The code I am using is:

```
UPDATE ships
SET "ISM Performance PM" = companies."ISM Performance PM"
WHERE sips."ISM IMO" = companies."ISM IMO"
```

Unfortunately, I end up like this:[image: Results]

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE ships
    SET "ISM Performance PM" = (SELECT companies."ISM Performance PM"
                                FROM companies
                                WHERE sips."ISM IMO" = companies."ISM IMO"
                               );
```